Error Running BACnet Python Script with BAC0: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
I'm encountering an issue while running a Python script for BACnet communication using the BAC0 library. The script is intended to set up a BACnet device on my Ubuntu server VM. However, when executing the script, I receive the following error:
[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

This error occurs during the initialization of the BAC0 application, specifically when attempting to bind the UDP socket to the specified IP address and port. Despite setting the IP address correctly, the script fails to assign the requested address.
Here are the relevant details:

I'm using the BAC0 library for BACnet communication.
The script runs without errors on my local machine (Windows 11).
I've verified the IP address assigned to my Ubuntu server VM (192.168.44.2) using the ifconfig command.
I've tried adjusting the subnet mask in the Python script, but the error persists.
I've also attempted running the script with elevated privileges using sudo, but the error remains unchanged.

It seems like the issue lies in the binding of the UDP socket to the specified IP address and port. I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this error and successfully run the BACnet Python script on my Ubuntu server VM. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
PS If you need my code:
from BAC0 import lite
from BAC0.core.devices.local.models import (
    analog_value,
    binary_value,
    multistate_value,

)
from BAC0.core.devices.local.object import ObjectFactory
from time import sleep

def parse_objects_from_file(file_path,device):
    ObjectFactory.clear_objects()
    _new_object = None
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        
    # Recherche de l'indice de la ligne après '#keyname'ou '# keyname'
    key_index = None
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith('# keyname') or line.startswith('#keyname') :
            key_index = i + 1
            break
    
    if key_index is None:
        print("Erreur: Aucune ligne contenant les données d'objet trouvée après '#keyname'")
        return
    
    # Filtrer les lignes pertinentes à partir de l'indice trouvé
    relevant_lines = lines[key_index:]
    i = 0
    for line in relevant_lines:
        i=i+1
        print(i)
        # Analyser la ligne et extraire les informations pour créer l'objet
        infos = line.split(';')
        print(line)

        # Créer l'objet BACnet en fonction du type

        if infos[3] == '2':  # Analog Value
            if infos[6]:
                present_value = float(infos[6].replace(',', '.'))
            else:
                present_value = 0.0
            print(infos[2])
            _new_object = analog_value(
                instance=int(infos[4]), name=infos[2], description= infos[5],presentValue=present_value
            )


        elif infos[3] == '3':  # Binary Value
                present_value_str = infos[6].strip()  # Supprimer les espaces autour de la chaîne
                print(infos[2])
                if present_value_str:  # Vérifier si la chaîne n'est pas vide
                    present_value = int(present_value_str)
                else:
                    present_value = 0  # Utiliser None si la chaîne est vide
                _new_object = binary_value(
                    instance=int(infos[4]), name=infos[2], description=infos[5], presentValue=present_value
                )


        elif infos[3] == '19':  # Multistate Value
            present_value_str = infos[6].strip()  # Supprimer les espaces autour de la chaîne
            print(infos[2])
            if present_value_str:  # Vérifier si la chaîne n'est pas vide
                present_value = int(present_value_str)
            else:
                present_value = 0  # Utiliser None si la chaîne est vide
            _new_object = multistate_value(
                instance=int(infos[4]), name=infos[2], description=infos[5], presentValue=present_value
            )
    if _new_object != None:
        _new_object.add_objects_to_application(device)






# Utilisation :
# Définir l'adresse IP et le masque de sous-réseau
ip_address = "192.168.44.2"
subnet_mask = "255.255.240.0"

# Concaténer l'adresse IP et le masque de sous-réseau
ip_with_subnet = ip_address + "/" + subnet_mask

# Utiliser l'adresse IP avec le masque de sous-réseau dans votre programme
device = lite(ip=ip_with_subnet, port='47808', deviceId='1')
ObjectFactory.clear_objects()
parse_objects_from_file("/home/fare/bactest/TD-R0_92010_Marcoule_BACnet_EDE_IndB_EDE.csv", device)

while True:
    sleep(5)

